# Ubuntu File Appearing As Directory

Tags: filesystem, files, directory

I have this php file that somehow is showing as a directory. It still has a php extension but when I cd the file I get:

```
base: cd: satisfaction.php: Input/output error
```

When I vim the file it looks like a directory.

Is there any way to chmod the file or something? I really don't want to remake this file as I did not get it up on the svn. Ugh! Please help.

Edit: `ls -lah` shows:

```
-???????? ?      ?      ?            ?  satisfaction.php
```

Edit 2:

```
chown -R tyejae:tyejae satisfaction.php
chown: cannot access 'satisfaction.php': Input/output error
```

Edit 3: file satisfaction.php

```
satisfaction.php: ERROR: cannot open 'satisfaction.php' (Input/output error)
```

Edit 4: stat satisfaction.php

```
stat: cannot stat 'satisfaction.php': Input/output error
```

Edit 5: cat satisfaction.php

```
cat: satisfaction.php: Input/output error
```

Comment: Please post the output of `file satisfaction.php` and `stat satisfaction.php`. That looks like a corrupted file.

Comment: file satisfaction.php
satisfaction.php: ERROR: cannot open 'satisfaction.php' (Input/output error)

stat Satisfaction.php
stat: cannot stat 'satisfaction.php': Input/output error

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add extra info, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. You can then ping the user who asked for the information by leaving a comment and including a `@` before their username. For example, to ping me: `@terdon`. Also, make sure you use the correct path for the file, `satisfaction.php` and `Satisfaction.php` are not the same file. Please [edit] and post the output of `stat /path/to/statisfaction.php` (change `/path/to` to the correct path of course).

Comment: OK, it looks like a filesystem problem, a corrupt file. Can you `cat satisfaction.php`?

Comment: @terdon Updated the information. Apologies about the uppercase Satisfaction.php, don't know why I mistakenly capitalized it when I posed the comment.

Comment: Yeah, that's a corrupted file, don't think you can do anything but delete and recreate it. You might also want to run a file system check.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. I guess I'll get started on recreating it. I ran an fsck before I posted and didn't get anything from it. I forgot to post that. Thanks again @terdon for the quick responses.